# macOS Catalina Downloading information to target volume failed ERROR

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina

I am trying to update macOS from Yosemite (10.10) to Catalina 10.15.) on my mac book pro 2015, I downloaded the installer from the app store on my mac but every time I click continue to set up the installation I get this error message that reads "downloading installer information to the target volume failed"

I tried many solutions and searched everywhere but no solutions so far, I tried to use a patcher that also didn't work. I tried to install it from the terminal but that also didn't work.

What could be the cause of this?

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you read this [Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475) about upgrading to Catalina? There are Mac hardware compatibility requirements. You don't mention the model of Mac you're using so, its hard to help at this point.

Comment: i am compatible, i am using mac book pro 2015 @IconDaemon

Comment: @IconDaemon and yes i read that document it didnt help very much. i am compatible and everything, what do i do now?

Comment: You are making a very large leap upgrading from Yosemite as you are skipping El Capitan, Sierra, High Sierra, and Mojave to Catalina.  You may have to upgrade to say Sierra first then upgrade to Catalina.  Also, I would definitely make sure you are not encrypted before you attempt upgrading. Turn off FileVault.  Make a backup.  Here's the link to Sierra - http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-39476-20191023-48f365f4-0015-4c41-9f44-39d3d2aca067/InstallOS.dmg

Comment: @JamesBrickley ok i will try what you suggested, thank you

Comment: @JamesBrickley i downloaded the link to sierra and followed the installation proccess but the software wasnt installed, it just gave me a success message and thats it. what do i do after that? i clicked on the installOS.pkg and followed the steps but how do i install sierra on my mac now?

Comment: Look for /Applications/Install macOS Sierra that's what the PKG created.

Comment: I provided an answer, one more point.  If Catalina fails to install while on Sierra then perhaps create a bootable Catalina flash drive (16GB+) and boot from that to perform the upgrade.  You might have to delete internal disk completely and clean install Catalina. BACKUP if you have data you want to keep. I believe it requires APFS which didn't change until High Sierra so unless you have a lot of data to migrate and no way to backup, upgrading to High Sierra then Catalina is even more time consuming.

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to not make such a large leap in operating system versions, skipping more than two macOS releases is inherently dangerous.  I sincerely doubt it receives the same kind of testing that an incremental upgrade would receive. Ideally, it would be recommended to backup your data and perform a clean installation of Catalina if you can create a bootable macOS flash drive possibly with another Mac.

However you can try upgrading to an intermediate version such as Sierra or High Sierra then upgrade that to Catalina.  A great deal has changed and the big one is the change from JHFS+ filesystem to the new APFS filesystem.

If your disk is encrypted you need to turn off FileVault or you are going to be at far greater risk of a major problem.

Here are the Apple Support pages where you can download various versions of macOS using special links. The downloads are hidden from the App Store via search or are distributed from backend CDN Apple storage. For High Sierra+ the downloads will be made from the App Store but older releases will come from a CDN (Content Distribution Network).

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202 - Sierra
This will download an InstallOS.pkg that creates the /Applications/Install macOS Sierra installer which needs to be run manually after the InstallOS.pkg.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969 - High Sierra

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210190 - Mojave

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475 - Catalina

Instructions on how to make a bootable installation for everything but Sierra
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

El Capitan can be rather difficult to get working, your mileage may vary. I've found it to be far easier to go with Sierra or High Sierra.

Comment: i did everything you suggested i upgraded until Mojave, but still when i try to update to catalina from the system itself it gives me the same error. whats the issue here?

Comment: What MacBook Pro model do you have?  Apple -> Help -> About this Mac.

Comment: im able to download catalina now but it keeps stopping half way through with the error "the request timed out , an error ocurred while downloading the update"

Answer (score 1):

CAUSE : SSD CRASH WITH CACHE DATA
SOLUTION :

1. FORMAT TO APS SYSTEM
2. FIRST AID THE DISK

then RE DOWNLOAD
100% WILL WORK

Comment: Yo nice - it worked. It took a while to get past the "Deleting" stage but it got there eventually. (This was all in recovery mode. Formatting your disk of course erases everything, so not sure this is helpful in wanting to simply upgrade the OS while preserving your files.)